# How to schedule a batch script for every 30 minutes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I want to know the batch script to be included in my present batch script to schedule it for every 30 minutes.

**myscript.bat**

```
@echo off

java -jar myscript.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to loop the script with a 30 minute timeout between execution of `java`, then:

```
@echo off
:start
java -jar myscript.jar
timeout /t 1800 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
goto :start
```

if you wanted to actually schedule it to run every 30 minutes, then use your task scheduler.